# Does Istio provide the ability to merge content of multiple backend APIs in a single endpoint?

Tags: istio, krakend

We're evaluating Istio and KrakenD for our API Gateway solution and trying to understand the differences in their functionality.  One thing that stood out in the KrakenD docs is its ability to merge the content of multiple backend APIs into a single endpoint response to caller, as well as the ability to filter the content of responses, to remove "extra" data and/or change the names of attributes, etc.  Trying to determine if Istio has similar capabilities but so far the Istio documentation hasn't been too helpful.

Does anyone has experience/info with this?

Answer (score 0):

As of `v1.16.x` istio does not have capability of aggregation and transformation out of the box.
But it supports Proxy Extensions with WASM plugin.
That allows you to write custom code to decorate request/response.
You can use any language as long as it compiles to WASM.

https://events.istio.io/istiocon-2021/slides/c8p-ExtendingEnvoyWasm-EdSnible.pdf

https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/wasm/